# Google Search Console Soft 404 for separate mobile and desktop URLs

Tags: google-search-console, mobile, soft-404, next.js

I have a webiste with two different URLs for mobile and desktop.
I linked everything with canonical and alternate tags and updated my sitemap.xml.

But the Google Search Console keeps throwing "**Soft 404**" Errors when testing most of the sites...

E.g. https://m.voyd.shop/kategorie/neu

The website automatically redirects the user to the desktop version, when the screen is wider than 700px.

Anybody knows the reason? There is definitely content and the URL did not change in month...

**EDIT**:
Some pictures for better understanding:

This is the result when checking for the desktop version of my website:
[image]

And this happens, when I apply for indexing the mobile version (Happens for weeks now...)
[image]

My sitemap for mobile version can be found here: https://m.voyd.shop/sitemap.xml

**UPDATE:**

I changed everything according to Kannan's answer, but I am still getting this message when trying to check the Live-URL:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
Just checked https://www.voyd.shop/kategorie/neu and still soft 404...

[image]

Comment: I have added more observations to my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

When I tried `curl --head` on your desktop page (URL in your screenshot), your server returns a `308` (permanent redirect) to the `www` version.

The desktop version of the URL that you are checking on Search Console is without `www`.

Google has no idea about what content could have existed in **non-`www`** page (if at all) before you placed a redirect to the **`www`** page. Hence, the redirect will be treated as a one to non-equivalent page. Thus you are receiving a soft 404.

Regarding mobile issues, I am unable to spot any serious issue other than having canonical client rendered (If I observed it correctly). The rendered source shows the correct canonical. The server-side rendered page (that Google sees at first) shows "undefined" in canonical. If that is the case, probably you should wait longer. (Ref: A similar issue is being discussed here: [Google showing static title instead of dynamically set javascript title](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/135861/google-showing-static-title-instead-of-dynamically-set-javascript-title)). Nevertheless, please make sure the canonical points to the `www` version.

Note: Why don't you have a single sitemap, thus making things easier for Google.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls#annotation-in-sitemaps

**UPDATE**

In the search console, just make sure that your property is (or includes) `www` version of your website. While checking URLs in the inspection bar, you would be checking `www.` prefixed ones.

In sitemaps, update all desktop URLs with `www.` prefix.

Regarding sitemap location, one in the desktop folder alone will be sufficient. (For details, please check the reference URL I have posted above)

**UPDATE**:

In addition to the `www` issue (please check the first part of this answer), there seem to be more problems. Now soft 404 is thrown for the `www` version (where technically a 200 is returned). .

Here are my observations: (These points  should apply to the mobile version's soft 404 issues as well)

The main part of the content is rendered client-side. To check the same, I turned off JavaScript and refreshed the
URL. (I blocked JS for the site in chrome://settings/content/javascript). Now all I can see are the menu and footer (general template content).

Google can treat pages with minimal elements/content as soft 404s. Reference: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/soft-404-errors#pageother

I know Googlebot can process JavaScript, but the process can take time (sometimes in the order of weeks to months). Reference: [What are the SEO implications of an established website shifting from server-side rendering to client side?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126425/what-are-the-seo-implications-of-an-established-website-shifting-from-server-sid)

**Solution**

Either you can wait or turn your implementation **server-side** (the most preferable solution in my view). Based on what I read, Next JS supports SSR - Server Side Rendering.

**My Doubt**

Though I know Google takes a lot of time to process client-side rendered pages, I am unaware of whether Google will go to the extreme of treating the pages with minimal content at the initial crawl as soft 404s till its rendering process is complete. But from your case, it looks likely. If you have the same doubt, you may post that as a separate question (important if you stick with client-side rendering).

Comment: I updated my project according to your suggestions. Unfortunately I still get the error message, when trying to do the Live-Test with "https://www.voyd.shop/kategorie/neu". Do I just need to wait a little bit longer for Google to recognize my changes and the removal of the mobile sitemap.xml? Or do I need to do any further changes in my domain property in Google Search Console? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Of course I tried to check https:// www.voyd.shop/kategorie/neu (without the space). Webmasters removed the prefix in my previous comment.

Comment: I hope the error was not soft 404 this time. What error did you get?

Comment: I updated my questions. A pop-up apperas, which says that the Live-URL could not be checked. Same message when trying to apply for indexing. Checking the mobile version of the page results in the same error message.

Comment: From what I observe, the issue may be due to client side rendering. Google takes time (weeks to months in some cases) to process the client side rendered pages.  Ref: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/javascript-seo-basics#how-googlebot-processes-javascript . (When it comes to SEO, server side rendering is better in terms of time it takes for Google to process,)

Comment: From headers, I could see you are using Vercel platform. I don't have much knowledge regarding that. However, you can contact their support to check if others had such issues. From your end make sure you follow the best practices outlined in https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/javascript-seo-basics#how-googlebot-processes-javascript .

Comment: I am using nextJs because of their SSR. There is no client side rendering actually. I will contact the support of Vercel. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just checked the URL again and now it shows agaian the soft 404 error. I updated my question with a screenshot. Could you maybe have another look at the header? Maybe I missed something... @Kannan

Comment: Thanks for your observations! It is true that the content of my product category page is rendered on the client side. Thats because we are making use of infinite scrolling and therefore we can not prerender the content. But I will try to render the first request on the server and all following requests on the client afterwards. That should provide some more content for Google when they are crawling the prodcut category pages. I will keep you up to date, if anything should change.